# vim in Console2 on Windows doesn't colour code?

Tags: vim, cygwin, text-editors, console2

I'm using Console2 on Windows with Cygwin. Using Windows vim (on my PATH), the colour coding doesn't seem to display in Console2?

[image: Console2]

Using vim from cmd does colour code.

[image]

Comment: I found the problem - it has to do with `.vimrc` overwriting Windows vim defaults - why does this take precedence? How can I edit Windows vim settings, i.e. `set shiftwidth=4`

Answer (score 0):

```
:echo $HOME
```

User vimrc file is under `$HOME/.vimrc`

For more information take a look at vim wiki page:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file